# Where did retain/release history in Instruments go?

Tags: xcode

Apparently Instruments had its UI rearranged recently, and now I can't find the option to record retain/release history for my objects, as well as other options like filtering which objects are recorded. Where did that stuff go? I think it all used to be in the right-hand pane, but it's gone.

I'm using version 8.3.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's now under File > Recording Options. From the [Xcode 8.3 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW160):

> ## Instruments
>
> ### New Features
>
> - Updated the Instruments user interface. (28503173)
>
>   *Inspector Refresh*
>
>   Instruments previously contained three inspector panes: Record
>     Settings, Display Settings, and Extended Detail. There are now two
>     inspector panes: Extended Detail and Run Info. Extended Detail remains
>     unchanged and continues to provide additional information about
>     selected data in the detail pane. The new Run Info inspector pane
>     displays information about the currently selected run, including the
>     recording device information and recording settings when the run was
>     taken.
>
>   Record Settings are now located in a Recording Options window. To
>     display this window, choose File > Recording Options, press
>     Option-Command-R, or click-and-hold the Record button in the toolbar
>     and choose Recording Options from the menu that appears. The Recording
>     Options window includes global and instrument-specific recording
>     options.
>
>   The Display Settings inspector pane was previously used to change the
>     graphing style of the timeline pane and to perform filtering in the
>     detail pane. These features have been moved to new locations. If an
>     instrument supports multiple graphing options, a down arrow now
>     appears beside the instrument's icon when the pointer is positioned
>     above the instrument in the timeline pane. Click the instrument's icon
>     to open a popover containing editable graphing options. The down arrow
>     appears only for instruments that have graphing options. Detail pane
>     filtering options, including the text filter field previously located
>     in the navigation bar of the detail pane, are now found at the bottom
>     of the detail pane.
>
>   *Visual Run Comparison*
>
>   The ability to view graphs for multiple runs at the same time in the
>     timeline pane has been removed. To switch between runs, choose
>     Previous Run or Next Run from the Instruments menu, or click a
>     navigation arrow in the activity viewer in the toolbar.
>
>   For more information, see Instruments Help. Open help by choosing
>     Help > Instruments Help.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why they hid that stuff.